# How to get collection and subcollction from parent collection in cloud firestore android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have user_info as parent collection. Under this parent collection it has single_list as child collection and some information. I want to get all values from parent collection. Please help me to find answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your use of terminology is a bit off.  You have a collection of `user_info` documents, and *each of those documents* has a sub-collection named `single_data`.

The difference here is that there isn't a single `single_data` subcollection.  There is one subcollection for each `user_info` document.

Since the subcollection has a static name, what you are looking to do is pretty straightforward using a [collection group query](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html).

```js
firebase.firestore().collectionGroup('single_data')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
       // Do something with the docs from across all the subcollections
     })
```

Comment: Thanks grey for answering my questions. I used collectionGroup  but it give only particular single_list which means it shows single_list under one of the one of the user_info. I want to show every single_list of all user_info.

Comment: See the document I linked to above.  It describes the concept of `collectionGroup()`.  Ensure your sub-collections have a consistent name.

Comment: single_data is conisistent subcollection only i down known whats wrong. i am getting particular "single_list" list

Comment: fireStore.collectionGroup("single_data")
            .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
                if (error != null) {
                    Log.d("Error", "Something went wrong")
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }
                if (value != null){
                    val allUser = ArrayList<AddPostInfoModel>()
                    val document = value.documents

Comment: document.forEach{
                        try {
                            val allListModel =  it.toObject(AddPostInfoModel::class.java)
                            if (allListModel != null) {
                                allUser.add(allListModel)
                            }
                        }catch (e : Exception){
                            e.printStackTrace()
                        }
                    }

Comment: I recommend posting a new question detailing what you have tried (the code in the above comments) and what the current behaviour is.  Trying to triage the problem via comments is ... going to be challenging :)  If you are okay to do so, please accept this answer so that this question is considered "closed" and we can continue the conversation  in your new question's post.

Comment: Thanks man...Thanks for commenting my post....problem solved

Comment: If so, then please set one of the answers to "accepted" so that the thread is noted as being "answered".  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
           FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        
                                db.collection("users_info")            
                                .get()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                            //Here you can add all documents Id to your documentIdList to fetch all sigle_data at once. 
                                                Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                
                                                 documentIdList.add(document.getId());
                                            }
                                   getAllSubCollSingleData(documentIdList);
                                        } else {
                                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
            
    public void getAllSubCollSingleData(List<Int> documentIdList){
                 for(int i=0;i<documentIdList.size();i++){
            
               
                        db.collection("users_info").document(documentIdList.get(i))(would be phone number)
                         .collection("single_data")  
                    
                                .get()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                            //Here you can get all documents in sub collection single_data
                                            
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
            }}
```

Comment: hi androidLearner.. how to get subcollection"single_data"  from "user_info"

Comment: please see updated answer @RSumanRadhakrishnan